# How can I "fake" wildcards in a BindingSource Filter string?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, filter, bindingsource, expression

I know you can put wildcards on the ends of a Filter string (i.e. '*blah*', but I want to know how to make the filter behave like there are wildcards in the middle of the string (i.e. '*bl*ah*') which DataColumn.Expression property does not allow.  I can't figure out the syntax for Filters (DataColumn.Expression) that would emulate this behavior?

```
'LIKE '*bl*' AND LIKE '*ah*'
```

is not sufficient because it will give me all strings with 'bl' and 'ah', regardless of their position in the string.

```
BindingSource.Filter = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this from long ago, but I figured out that it cannot reasonably be done.  It just appears to be the nature of pattern matching with BindingSource filters.